# What's the expected value of this quantity? My attempt included

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose we have a sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \Bbb N^*}$ that follows the distribution $\frac{1}{n}\delta_{n^2}+(1-\frac{1}{n})\delta_0$.

What's the expected $E(X_n^p)$ with $p \geq 1$???

My attempt : $$E(X_n^p)=\sum_{n \in \Bbb N^*} n^p P(X_n=n) $$ which is equal to : $$E(X_n^p)=\sum_{n \in \Bbb N^*} \frac{n^p}{n^2}=\sum_{n \in \Bbb N^*} n^{p-2} $$ which goes to infinity.

Comment: But $X_n$ takes just the two values $0$ and $n^2$, so $E(X_n^p) =0^p\cdot(1-1/n)+(n^2)^p\cdot (1/n) = n^{2p-1}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins you are right, thanks